# In Swift is there a difference between the rotation in these two scenarios

Tags: swift, performance, animation

Example 1:

```
            let halfPie = Double.pi / 2
            var pieCount: Int = 0


            let rotationNum = (pieCount % 4) + 1
            let angle = halfPie * Double(rotationNum)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle))
            }) { [weak self] _ in
                self?.pieCount += 1
            }
```

Example 2:

```
            let halfPie = 1.5707963267949
            var pieCount: Int = 1


            let angle = halfPie * Double(pieCount)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle))
            }) { [weak self] _ in
                self?.pieCount += 1
            }
```

The difference between the two is that the second continues to increase, and the first keeps the number to max at PIE * 2. Is there any reason to impliment it one way over the other? They both seem to do the same thing.
pieCount is initialized globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference.

If you animate to 180° or 540°, the animation will be the same since the view will do the least amount of movement to get to the correct position.

---

On a side note, you shouldn't be hardcoding `halfPie` you should use `Double.pi/2`

Comment: Are M_PI and Double.pi the same thing?

Comment: `M_PI` is the old C way to get pi. Each floating point type in swift has pi defined so you don't need to convert the type. `Double.pi`, `CGFloat.pi`, `Float80.pi`, etc.

Comment: Nice..... That makes life easier. I forget why, but I didn't like using M_PI for some reason. Double.pi seems to act as i want it to though.

Comment: I knew the animation would be the same, but does 180 degrees vs 540 degrees get handled differently? Like is it more memory intensive to do it where it keeps growing. If not, then it takes less math to achieve. If it is (because it could grow as large as 180000), then it would be better to stick with example one. I know it probably matters very little, but nowadays things like this are what I get most curious about.

Comment: In most situations you can just say `.pi`, as the numeric type will be inferred.